# Proving a Probability Limit is Non Zero

Tags: calculus, probability, limits, statistics, proof-writing

I am reading [these lecture notes](https://courses.washington.edu/b571/lectures/notes131-181.pdf): on page 1, it mentions (indirectly) that :

- Define the Score Function as the first derivative of the likelihood
- If the Expected Value of the Score Function is not equal to 0, then the resulting MLE estimator will not be [Consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_(statistics)).

**I am trying to understand why this is true.**

I understand that this is the definition of Consistency in Statistics: An estimator $\hat{\theta}$ is consistent if when the sample size $n$ grows to infinity, the empirical estimator $\hat{\theta}_n$ subtracted from the theoretical estimator $\theta$ has a 0 probability of being greater than some small number $\epsilon$:

$$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} P(|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta| > \epsilon) = 0$$

I also understand how to obtain the Score Function for a given Likelihood Function:

1. A random variable $X$.
2. A probability density function (pdf) $f(x; \theta)$.
3. The likelihood of $f(x; \theta)$ given data $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ is

$$L(\theta; x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i; \theta)$$

4. The log-likelihood is

$$\log L(\theta; x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log f(x_i; \theta)$$

5. The derivative of the log-likelihood is

$$\frac{d}{d\theta} \log L(\theta; x) = \frac{d}{d\theta} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log f(x_i; \theta)$$

6. The MLE estimator of $\theta$ is the only solution $\hat{\theta}$
   of the equation
   $$\frac{d}{d\theta} \log L(\theta; x) = 0,$$
   provided this equation has a unique solution.
7. The expected value of the derivative of the log-likelihood is zero, i.e.,

$$E\left[\frac{d}{d\theta} \log L(\theta; x)\right] = 0$$

**My Question:** But mathematically, how can we show that if $E\left[\frac{d}{d\theta} \log L(\theta; x)\right] \neq 0$ , then $$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} P(|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta| > \epsilon) \neq 0$$ ???

Can someone please show me how this can be proven?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is the proof that you were looking for but, note that, if the derivative of the log likelihood is not zero, then the resulting $\hat{\theta}$ is not the MLE so it is won't be consistent asymptotically.There's a proof somewhere that all MLE's are CAN ( consistently asymptotically normal ).

Comment: Note that the CAN proof might be in one of LeCam's papers or books but his stuff can difficult to read.

Comment: thank you everyone for your replies! can anyone provide an answer to this?

Comment: Note, the expected value of the score function *at the true parameter value* should be zero.

Comment: @ Annika: thank you so much for your reply! If you have time, can you please write an answer! Your answers are always very detailed and I learn a lot from them!

Comment: @Annika provided certain regularity conditions hold

Comment: @JoseAvilez correct

Comment: @stats_noob gave it a shot --  basically you tie strong consistency of the MLE to the definition of maximizer having derivative zero.

Answer (score 1):

Hi: Note that this is not an answer ( I needed the space ) but here is a proof that the maximum likelihood estimator is consistent
Unfortunately, that does not prove that, if the estimator is not the MLE, then it is NOT consistent. So, this is close to a proof but it's not quite there.

https://www2.econ.iastate.edu/classes/econ671/hallam/documents/Asymptotic_Dist.pdf

I'm not clear on how to prove that the proof is an if and only if.

#====================================================================

ADDENDUM: Later on I found this. It is a thread showing how the MLE convergence proof breaks down when you don't use the MLE in the various steps. So, with a lot of effort, you can probably use this to prove the other direction. I don't have time to go through the details and show it but Alecos' threads tend to be VERY CLEAR.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127527/in-max-likelihood-the-expected-score-is-zero-for-the-true-values-is-it-also-tr

#===================================================================
11-01-2023: SECOND ADDENDUM TO ANSWER. THIS ONE REALLY IS AN ANSWER.
#======================================================================

stats_noob: I don't have time to write it all out but, re-reading the actual question you posed, it eventually hit me that it's not as hard as I suspected.

STEP 1) Take asymptotic_dist.pdf and read the first 3 sections  extremely carefully atleast upto and including equation 17).

STEP 2) Notice that 17) uses the fact that the expected value of the score ( which is the first derivative of the log likelihood ) = 0. !!!!

STEP 3) But, in the statement of the question, you state the expected value of the score does not equal zero. Therefore, the proof used in the "Consistency of the MLE" section, namely section 3, breaks down and we are done. QED.

If you don't follow above, let me know. But I think that answer is sufficient. To summarize: Statement in question causes plim of $\beta_{0}$ in second order taylor expansion to not be zero.
This ruins the consistency proof so that the aforementioned MLE described in the question statement cannot be consistent.

-

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x;\theta)$ be a family of probability densities or probability mass functions and let $\theta_0$ be the true value of the parameter $\theta$.

As mentioned in the comments, we need some regularity conditions. For example, the likelihood needs to be differentiable in some neighborhood around the true parameter value and cannot be on the boundary of the parameter space.

For any $\theta \neq \theta_0$ we have, by Jensen's Inequality:

$$E_{\theta_0}\left[\log \frac{f(X;\theta)}{f(X;\theta_0)}\right] \leq \log E_{\theta_0}\left[\frac{f(X;\theta)}{f(X;\theta_0)}\right]=0$$

To see why, take the continuous case (discrete case is analogous using $\sum$ or this can be expressed in a unified way using Lebesgue integration):

$$E_{\theta_0}\left[\frac{f(X;\theta)}{f(X;\theta_0)}\right] = \int_{\chi}\left[\frac{f(X;\theta)}{f(X;\theta_0)}\right] f(X;\theta_0) dx = \int_{\chi} f(X;\theta) dx = 1$$

This inequality is strict unless $f(x;\theta) = f(x;\theta_0)$ almost everywhere.

Now, let's take a $\delta>0$ to define two quantities:

$$k_1 =E_{\theta_0}\left[\log \frac{f(X;\theta_0-\delta)}{f(X;\theta_0)}\right]$$

and

$$k_2 =E_{\theta_0}\left[\log \frac{f(X;\theta_0+\delta)}{f(X;\theta_0)}\right]$$

Note that $k_1,k_2 < 0$ by our earlier inequality.

Define $\ell_n(x;\theta) := \log \frac{f(x;\theta)}{f(x;\theta_0)}$

Then by the Strong Law of Large Numbers (SLLN):

$$\frac{\ell_n(x;\theta_0-\delta)-\ell_n(x;\theta_0)}{n} \xrightarrow{a.s.} k_1$$

and similarly

$$\frac{\ell_n(x;\theta_0+\delta)-\ell_n(x;\theta_0)}{n} \xrightarrow{a.s.} k_2$$

Therefore, there is an $N$ such that for $\ell_n(x;\theta_0\pm \delta) < \ell_n(x;\theta_0)$ for all $n>N, \delta >0$. By differentiability of the likelihood, we know there exists some $\hat \theta \in ( \theta_0 - \delta, \theta_0 + \delta)$ that maximizes the likelihood. Since this holds for all $\delta> 0$ this means that the MLE is a strongly consistent estimator.

Since $\theta_0$ maximizes the likelihood, we know $$E_{\theta_0}\left[\frac{d \ell_n(x;\theta)}{d \theta}|_{\theta=\theta_0}\right] = 0$$

Comment: That was interesting but stats_noob wants to show the negative I think. By this I mean that he wants to show that, if the parameter doesn't satisfy the derivative being zero ( so not the MLE), then it can't be a consistent estimator. Atleast that's how I took the question. Thanks.

Comment: @ Annika: Thank you so much for your answer! I am currently also working on these questions as well - do you have any ideas about them? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4796679/why-is-this-optimization-problem-difficult  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4796714/can-we-prove-that-one-of-these-expressions-is-bigger-than-the-other

Comment: @ Mark leeds: thank you so much for your reply! Yes, you are correct - this is what I am looking for. Do you have any idea how to approach this problem? thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob: As I said, I think Alecos' approach ( in my addendum ) is the way to proceed. I will print out that thread and look at it either tonight or tomorrow. My guess is that I won't succeed but I surprise myself once in a while !!!!!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will review this. I was hoping to see a mathematical answer and must have missed it

Comment: Do you have any ideas about this one? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4796679/why-is-this-optimization-problem-difficult