# Why is this optimization problem difficult?

Tags: probability, optimization

A Normal (Gaussian) Probability Distribution Function can be defined as follows:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }$$

Now, we can create an linear weighted (with weights $\pi_i$ ) sum of these Normal Distributions. This is usually referred to as a Mixture Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution):

\begin{align*}
p(x|\theta) &= \sum_{i=1}^{k} \pi_i \mathcal{N}(x|\mu_i, \sigma_i^2) 
\end{align*}

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \pi_i = 1$$

Now, suppose we want to estimate all parameters (i.e. $\theta$ = $\pi_i$, $\mu_i$, $\sigma_i$ )  of this function (i.e. all $\pi_i$, $\mu_i$, $\sigma_i$)

In Statistics, we usually estimate these parameters using Maximum Likelihood Theory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation):

\begin{align*}
L(\theta|X) &= \prod_{j=1}^{n} p(x_j|\theta) = \prod_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{k} \pi_i \mathcal{N}(x_j|\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)
\end{align*}

From here, we would set the following derivatives to 0 and solve for these parameters (for all $i$):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \pi_i} \log L(\theta|X) = 0 $$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu_i} \log L(\theta|X) = 0 $$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma_i} \log L(\theta|X) = 0 $$

However, apparently if we try to solve the above optimization problem using standard Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE), we run into a problem of "Identifiability". Supposedly, one of the main problem that arises when using MLE is that for a given set of  $\mu_i$, $\sigma_i$  - the values of $\pi_i$ can be interchanged with one another and still produce the same value of the objective function being optimized. But I don't really understand why this is a bad thing. This just means that there are many solutions that satisfy this optimization problem: Nothing good, nothing bad - just a fact. There are many (equally) valid solutions to this optimization problem.

To fix this supposed problem, the EM algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) is used.

**My Question:** I don't understand why this happens. Suppose if I just proceed anyways and use MLE - how is this a undesirable? And how would using EM fix this supposed problem?

**Could someone please help me understand why MLE is not well suited for the above optimization problem and why the EM algorithm can be beneficial here? If there are multiple values of $\pi_i$ that can satisfy this optimization problem - won't the EM algorithm run into the same problem?**

Thanks!

**Note:**

- I have heard some people say that the EM algorithm is sometimes more computationally efficient/feasible  than MLE - but this is not the point I am interested in.
- I also heard that the function being optimized  (mixture distribution) is multi-modal and is a difficult function to optimize through MLE - but I am not sure how exactly the EM algorithm has an advantage over MLE in this regard.
- I heard that the main advantage of the EM algorithm is that it can remedy fundamental mathematical problems (i.e. identifiability) that MLE runs into - but I can't understand what these problems are to begin with and why EM can be useful compared to MLE in this regard. How does the EM algorithm handle identifiability problems better than MLE?

**References:**

- https://stephens999.github.io/fiveMinuteStats/intro_to_em.html
- https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s42952-022-00180-6
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262538/why-expectation-maximization-is-important-for-mixture-models
- https://people.csail.mit.edu/rameshvs/content/gmm-em.pdf
- https://ardianumam.wordpress.com/2017/11/07/how-em-expectation-maximization-method-works-for-clustering/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2HIW37Ohho

Comment: The EM algorithm is a way to compute the MLE - you're comparing two things in different categories.

Comment: +1 to giorgi's comment: EM is a way to compute the MLE. Regarding why we use EM in the first place: if I recall correctly, the reason for using EM is not the identifiability issue. Rather, after setting all the derivatives to zero, it is not possible to analytically solve for the maximizing parameters. This is mentioned in the stephens999 reference that you linked.

Comment: @ giorgi nguyen : thank you so much for these clarifications!

Comment: @  angryavian: thank you so much for your reply! do you think you can please explain why if you use MLE and set all the derivatives to 0 ... why is it not possible to analytically solve? Is it because there are more parameters than equations? And why is EM able to work better here?

Comment: It's not that it's always impossible, it's just really hard! Try to solve those optimality conditions yourself for a moderately complicated problem (say, $n=3$ and $k=10$) and you will quickly see.

Comment: @ giorgi nguyen: thank you so much for your reply! but why does EM algorithm help in this regard?

Comment: You can think of the EM algorithm as an iterative algorithm to solve an optimization problem, similar to (but not the same as) gradient descent or Newton's method. I think you can actually view EM as a special case of coordinate descent.

Comment: @  angryavian :just to confirm, the classic MLE algorithm CAN technically be used in this case... its just not very effective?

Comment: MLE is not really an algorithm. It is an estimator defined as the solution of a certain optimization problem. Solving the optimization problem is sometimes easy, but sometimes hard.

Comment: Is this considered a tractable likelihood?

Comment: I suggest improving the title to make it more reachable by MSE community: you may add one or two of the key terms "EM algorithm" and "Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE)" in the title. I suggest this: Is Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) easier using EM algorithm for mixture distributions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the weights $\pi_i$ are fixed, the following function

\begin{align*}
L(\theta|x) &= \prod_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{k} \pi_i \mathcal{N}(x_j|\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)
\end{align*}

is non-concave with **multiple local maxima** with respect to the vector $\theta$ (to see that the likelihood is non-concave let $n=1$, $k=1$ with $\pi_1=1$,  $\sigma_1^2=1$, then the function $\mathcal{N}(x_1|\mu_1, 1)$ is neither concave nor convex in $\mu_1$, the shape of  the function looks like the normal PDF). The situation becomes worse when $\pi_i$ are allowed to vary. Even for small size, it is difficult to find all the corresponding all feasible KKT points numerically (to determine the global maximizer). The EM also cannot find the global optima of the above problem.

There are various algorithms for maximization of concave functions (minimization of convex functions) over convex feasible sets, none of them work here.

Such intractable optimization problems are studied under the umbrella of the term Global Optimization. You can find many books on this topic.

Note that using **heuristic optimization methods** to find ML estimates is **not recommended** from a statistical point of view because what is found is no longer follows the desirable properties of ML estimators.

**When the size of $\theta$ is small** (for example when mixing 4 normal distributions), I strongly suggest directly finding the optimizer with desired precision by **the direct search method** based on some for loops in python or R (instead of using complex Global Optimization methods that converge global optima under restrictive conditions). Recall that the number of for loops are not affected by the sample size.

For using the direct search method, first we need to find lower and upper bounds for each parameter. Then, a precision level should be determined  for each parameter. Next, we need to write nested for loops, to find the global optima. It works in many practical cases.

For the case of mixing 4 normal distributions, we have $4\times 2+3$ parameters. The weights $\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3$ are bounded (note $\pi_4=1-\pi_1-\pi_2-\pi_3$ and the 3 loops for $\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3$ should be formed such that the summation of $\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3$ is less than or equal to 1). For the other $4\times 2$ parameters, based on the data one can determine very pessimestic bounds. For example, we can consider that the means are numbers between the smallest and largest values, i.e., $\left [X_{(1)},X_{(n)} \right ]$, and the variances are positive numbers less than the squared range of the data, i.e., $ \left ( 0, \left ( X_{(n)}-X_{(1)} \right )^2 \right ] $. The precision level used for gridding each interval can be any small number such as 0.0001. One can also carry sensitivity analyses to make sure that the selected bounds and precision levels are set adequately. All of these can be done in a few minutes on an ordinary PC when the size of $\theta$ is small, without the need of implementing complex methods that do not guarantee any globality or accuracy for their output solutions.

The **EM algorithm** is used for solving the optimization problem appearing in a generalization of the ML method in which the likelihood function is expressed as the expectation of the likelihood function of some observable and unobservable random variables with respect to the distribution of the unobservable random variables. This can be nicely applied to mixture models, by assuming that each sample is randomly assigned to one of the basic distributions (the latent variable determines the true distribution for each observation). For the family of exponential distributions (including normal distributions), this idea is very elegant because at each iteration the maximization problem can be solved easily. However, there is **no guarantee that the EM converges to a global optimum**, while it always converges to an extreme point, with zero gradient, which can be a local minimum, a local maximum, or a saddle point (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83387/why-is-the-expectation-maximization-algorithm-guaranteed-to-converge-to-a-local#:%7E:text=EM%20is%20not%20guaranteed%20to,get%20stuck%20at%20saddle%20points) for more details). Hence, what it is obtained by the EM algorithm is not useful and **is not necessarily an ML estimate**.

Let me return to the main point motivating the original question: Why is the EM algorithm much better suited for this mixture optimization problem compared to a numerical MLE approach?

My answer: The EM algorithm can find some solution easily from a computational perspective, though it is a heuristic and what it finds  may not be an ML estimate.

For the case of 3 mixtures, we have 6+2 parameters, 6 parameters ($\mu_1,\mu_1, \mu_1, \sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3$) and 2 mixing parameters ($\pi_1,\pi_2; \pi_3=1-\pi_1-\pi_2$). The ML method deals with an 8-dimentiolanl optimization problem, while the EM algorithm **tires** to solve the 8-dimentiolanl optimization problem by solving a series of 2-dimentional easy optimization problems in M step where the 2-dimentional problems are sequentially updated in E step. It is why some may think that the EM algorithm is better for mixture distributions (it simply works), while it is **not true** because the outputs of the EM algorithm are not necessarily ML estimates.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! two questions I had about this:

Comment: 1) so technically, you can use a standard numerical MLE solution (e.g. fisher scoring) for this  .... but its not recommended?

Comment: 2) why does the situation become worse when pi_i is allowed to vary? and by intractable, you mean "complicated function"?

Comment: @stats_noob You are very welcome! I just added some details on the EM algorithm. Regarding the questions, you may consider that if the likelihood function (or its log) is concave in the parameters, Fisher scoring or other known continuous optimization methods converge to global optima (ML estimate) under some mild conditions. However, in the above case that the likelihood function is not concave even if the weights are fixed, there is no guarantee that such optimization methods converge to a global optimum (indeed multiplying each function with a new variable makes the function more complex).

Comment: Computationally intractable here means that there is still no known procedure that can find the global optima of the optimization problem within reasonable run times that are acceptable in practice.

Comment: @ Amir: thank you so much for these clarifications! "However, in the above case that the likelihood function is not concave even if the weights are fixed," How do we know this? Is there an easy way to find this out?

Comment: B: I am also trying to understand why this mixture optimization problem is so difficult. For instance, suppose there are two coins : each coin has a selection probability (p1 and 1-p1) and a success probability (q1, q2). We observe a sequence of flips HHTHTHTHH ... and now we want to estimate  p1, q1 and q2 (i.e. in  which order were these coins flipped that maximize the probability of generating this observed sequence).

Comment: B (cont) :  If you write the likelihood, it becomes enormous (e.g imagine drawing the tree where p1, q1 and a2 = 0 to 1 by 0.1). When there are N coins, the likelihood is impossible. EM can reduce the  optimization space by making this problem into 2 smaller sub problems and find a local min/max. Is all my reasoning correct?

Comment: A: The main point that motivated the original question: Why is the EM algorithm much better suited for this mixture optimization problem compared to a numerical MLE approach? It seems to me that this mixture optimization problem is difficult no matter which approach you use . If you have three mixtures, you have 6 parameters (mu1,mu2, mu3, sigma1, sigma2, sigma3) and 2 latent parameters (p1, p2, 1-p2). Numerical MLE would treat this a 8 dimensional problem whereas EM would treat these as one 6 dimensional problem (E step) and one 2 dimensional problem (M step). Is this why EM is better?

Comment: @stats_noob Thank you for the comments. I tired to improve the answer by including more details. I showed why the likelihood is not concave, and discussed why people mistakenly think the EM is better for mixed distributions.

Comment: @ Amir: thank you so much for all your help! Can you please explain what you mean by "The EM algorithm can find some solution easily from a computational perspective, though it is a heuristic and what it finds may not a (be?) valid ML (Maximum Likelihood) estimate."? What is meant by "valid" here? I would have thought it would be the other around - Maximum Likelihood might not return a "valid" estimate (e.g. sum of pi > 1 , negative variance). Can you please explain what you mean by "valid" and why the EM algorithm might not return a valid estimate?

Comment: "while it is not true because the outputs of the EM algorithm are not necessarily ML estimates." here you mean that the final estimates produced by the EM algorithm will not fully satisfy the ML equations ... and therefore estimates from EM wont have the same properties as estimates from ML (e.g. asymptotic normality, consistency)?

Comment: I posted a related question here with some follow up thoughts ... maybe you might be interested in checking it out? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4803163/why-is-gradient-descent-always-chosen-for-neural-networks ... i.e. if (stochastic) gradient descent works so effectively for neural networks... why cant we just use gradient descent for mixture models?

Comment: @stats_noob I just removed "valid", it was for emphasis, because some consider the output of the EM algorithm as an ML estimate, while it is not a real one  (estimates obtained from EM won't have the same properties as ML estimates (e.g. asymptotic normality, consistency), because it may not maximize the likelihood function, which is the basic definition of the ML estimate. ... Sure I will check the new question!