# Why is Gradient Descent always chosen for Neural Networks?

Tags: probability, optimization, machine-learning, gradient-descent, neural-networks

**I am trying to understand why Gradient Descent are the chosen types of algorithm for optimizing the Loss Function in Neural Networks - and why other algorithms** (e.g. EM Algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) **are not.**

**Part 1:** Recently, I posted a question ([Why is this optimization problem difficult?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4796679/why-is-this-optimization-problem-difficult)) on understanding why the EM algorithm is a good choice for a  difficult optimization problem involving estimating the parameters for a **mixture of Normal Probability Distributions**:

\begin{align*}
p(x|\theta) &= \sum_{i=1}^{k} \pi_i \mathcal{N}(x|\mu_i, \sigma_i^2) 
\end{align*}

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \pi_i = 1$$

Optimization Problem:
\begin{align*} 
L(\theta|X) &= \prod_{j=1}^{n} p(x_j|\theta) = \prod_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{k} \pi_i \mathcal{N}(x_j|\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)
\end{align*}

We are interested in estimating the vector  $\theta$ = $\pi_i$, $\mu_i$, $\sigma_i$ )  of this function (i.e. all $\pi_i$, $\mu_i$, $\sigma_i$ such that the resulting estimates produce the largest value of $L(\theta|X)$.

For this type of optimization problem, the EM algorithm is the standard choice (note: $Z = \pi_i$ ).

- Step 1: First, choose initial values for the parameters $\theta^{(0)} = \{\pi_i, \mu_i, \sigma_i^2\}$ for all $i = 1, ..., k$.
- (E Step) Step 2: Next, compute the expected value of the log-likelihood function, with respect to the conditional distribution of $Z$ given $X$ under the current estimate of the parameters $\theta^{(i)}$ : $Q(\theta|\theta^{(i)}) = E_{Z|X,\theta^{(i)}}[log L(\theta;X,Z)]$.
- (M Step) Step 3:  Find the parameter that maximizes this quantity: $\theta^{(i+1)} = argmax_{\theta} Q(\theta|\theta^{(i)})$.
- Step 4: Repeat the E-step and M-step until convergence.

This optimization problem is considered to be a very difficult optimization problem as it is multi-modal (i.e. many local minima/maxima) as well as the fact that switching the values of $\pi_i$ while keeping $\mu_i$, $\sigma_i\$ constant can result in the same values of the function being optimized.

Essentially, the EM algorithm breaks the original optimization problem into two smaller sub-problems that are easier to optimize, and it can be mathematically proven that this approach can guarantee that the value of the loss function improves with each successive iteration.

**Part 2:** For a generic **Neural Network**, the loss function being optimized can be written as:

\begin{equation}
L(w_1, w_2, ..., w_n) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} L_i(y_i, f(x_i; w_1, w_2, ..., w_n))
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\nabla L(\mathbf{w}) = \left[ \frac{\partial L(\mathbf{w})}{\partial w_1}, \frac{\partial L(\mathbf{w})}{\partial w_2}, ..., \frac{\partial L(\mathbf{w})}{\partial w_n} \right]^T
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
w_{i}^{(j+1)} = w_{i}^{(j)} - \eta \frac{\partial L(w_1^{(j)}, w_2^{(j)}, ..., w_n^{(j)})}{\partial w_{i}^{(j)}}
\end{equation}

**My Question:** As we can see from the above equations, optimizing Neural Networks are also high dimensional and multimodal (i.e. based on the dimensions of $w_i$) - the corresponding Loss Functions are said to be highly non-convex with multiple local minima/maxima and saddle points. But Gradient Descent is used here instead of the EM algorithm. Can anyone please explain why this is the case? **Why is EM so well suited for mixture models and Gradient Descent so well suited for Neural Networks?** **How do these two optimization problems differ and complexity such that one is usually done with EM and the other with Gradient Descent?**

Thanks!