# Can we prove that one of these expressions is bigger than the other?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following expressions:

- Expression 1: $a ({I} (X^{T} X)^{-1})$

where $a$ is a scalar

- Expression 2: $[(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}] (aB) [(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}]^{T}$

Where B is a symmetric, positive semi-definite matrix

**My Question:** Is it somehow possible to show that Expression 1 will always be smaller than Expression 2?

Thanks!

**Notes:**

- I am learning about a problem in Statistics and Probability where the "true" answer to the problem is in the form of Expression 2 and the "proposed" answer is in the form of Expression 1. Generally, we are told that Expression 1 will "underestimate" the true answer - I am trying to work through some of the math to see why this is true.
- If anyone is interested, the exact problem involves showing that : When you have correlated errors in a Simple  Linear Regression, the Variance estimates from Classical Ordinary Least Squares (Expression 1) will underestimate the true variance (Expression 2). For the purpose of this question, I thought it would be easier to ask this question with the background and simply ask this question in terms of comparing the general expressions

Comment: Is Expression 2 supposed to be $[(X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top] (aB) [(X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top]^\top$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct! Thank you for pointing this out... I will fix it

Comment: @angryavian : do you have any idea how to answer this question?

Comment: What is $X$? A square matrix?

Comment: @  Hagen von Eitzen: X is not necessarily a square matrix .... but I think that XtX will be a square matrix

Comment: does anyone have any ideas about this? thank you so much

Comment: Both expressions are matrices, so it is not clear what you mean by "larger." From your last bullet point, it seems you are interested in variance, so are you trying to show that the diagonal elements in Expression 1 are smaller than their counterparts in Expression 2?